# A question about annihilator of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $Y$ be a proper subspace of $X$. Define the annihilator of $Y$ by

$$Ann(Y):=\{f\in X^*:~f(y)=0~\forall~y\in Y\}.$$

Note that
$$Y\subseteq \bigcap\limits_{f\in Ann(Y)}\ker f.$$

My question is whether $Y=\bigcap\limits_{f\in Ann(Y)}\ker f$? Or, can we find an example, where $Y$ is a proper subset of $\bigcap\limits_{f\in Ann(Y)}\ker f.$ Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming $X^*$ refers to the topological dual, then you don't get equality when $Y$ is not closed (as the right hand side is the intersection of closed subspaces).

Comment: Thank you @TheoBendit! When $Y$ is closed, will the above inequality become an equality? Probably an application of Geometric Hahn-Banach Theorem?

Comment: Yes, exactly!${}$

Comment: Oh thank you @TheoBendit

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4109751/relation-between-y-and-y-perp-in-a-banach-space/4110382#4110382

Comment: Thankyou @JustDroppedIn