# Relation between $Y$ and $Y^{\perp}$ in a Banach space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Given any normed linear space $X$ let $Y$ be a subspace of $X$. Define

$$Y^\perp:=\{f\in X^* :~ f(y)=0~\forall~y\in Y\}.$$

I have stuck in a problem which asks to show that if $Y$ is closed, then

$$Y=\bigcap\limits_{g\in Y^\perp} \ker g.$$

As a hint: it says apply geometric Hahn-Banach Theorem or Mazur's separation Theorem.

I do not know, how to proceed.

**EDIT** I did the forward $\subseteq$ part in the comment. I am trying the reverse part following the comment of UmbertoP.

Let $W=\bigcap\limits_{g\in Y^\perp} \ker g$ and let $x\in W\setminus Y$. Then due to the closedness of $Y$ and compactness of $\{y\}$, we can find a convex neighborhood about the **zero** vector say $V$ such that

$$(Y+V)\cap (x+V)=\emptyset.$$

In particular, $Y$ is disjoint from a convex open set $(x+V)$. By Mazur's Theorem, there exists a closed hyperplane $H$ containing $Y$ and disjoint from $(x+V)$. Consider a linear functional $h$ with $\ker h=H$. Then this $h$ is continuous, annihilates $Y$. So, $h\in Y^\perp$ but $x\notin \ker h$, a contradiction.

Please help me regarding this.

Comment: Can you prove either $\subset$ or $\supset$?

Comment: $\subset$ this part I can prove. For every $g\in Y^\perp$, $Y\subseteq \ker g$. Therefore, $Y\subseteq \bigcap\limits_{g\in Y^\perp} \ker g$. But no idea about the converse@UmbertoP.

Comment: Try the following: if $x \in X \setminus Y$ then there exists $g \in Y^\perp$ with $g(x) \not= 0$. I think this is a straightforward application of Hahn-Banach (assuming $Y$ is closed).

Comment: Thankyou @UmbertoP. I have added an edit following your comment. Please let me know, if there is any concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $y\in Y$. If $g\in Y^\bot$, then $g(y)=0$, so $y\in\ker(g)$, therefore $$Y\subset\bigcap_{g\in Y^\bot}\ker(g)$$
Conversely, assume that $x\in X$ satisfies $g(x)=0$ for all $g\in Y^\bot$. If $x\not\in Y$, then, since $Y$ is closed, by the Hahn-Banach theorem [and its consequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2025803/consequence-of-the-hahn-banach-theorem) there exists $f\in X^*$ so that $f\vert_Y=0$ and $f(x)=\text{dist}(x,Y)>0$. This is a contradiction, because $f\in Y^\bot$, so it must be $f(x)=0$. Thus $x\in Y$, so
$$\bigcap_{g\in Y^\bot}\ker(g)\subset Y.$$